# How do I create single row publication records with multiple authors in SQL in order to generate XML?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Some context: I have an Oracle DB with publication records. I am trying to generate XML files, containing all publications authored or edited by a specific person. However, the XML needs to contain the co-authors as well (and a bunch of other information, which does not cause any trouble).

Relevant code:

```
select  NAME_FIRST_NAME,
        NAME_LAST_NAME,
        LIST_INDEX,
        PUBLICATION_ID

from CLASSIFIED_AUTHOR_ASSOC CAA
join PUBLICATION        PUB
on CAA.PUBLICATION_ID = PUB.ID

where CAA.PUBLICATION_ID IN 
    (select PUBLICATION_ID 
    from CLASSIFIED_AUTHOR_ASSOC 
    where PERSON_ID = '127746')

order by CAA.PUBLICATION_ID, CAA.LIST_INDEX ASC
```

Sample output:

Bob Johnson 0 996822

Bob Johnson 0 962544

Bob Johnson 0 455211

Sue Hopkins 1 455211

The list_index value is important because it indicates the order of the authors, which is relevant. The issue is that I have multiple rows for a single publication.

I have been looking into pivoting functions, but they all seem oriented towards numerical values and imply that you know in advance how many rows you will end up with (the records in my data set have anything between 1 and 30 authors). My question is: how do I best approach this problem? Do I aggregate the authors in a single column? In this case, I have no idea how to get them in distinct xml-elements afterwards. Or is there another way to achieve what I want to do?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have found the following partially solves my problem:

´select  
    min (case LIST_INDEX when 0 then NAME_FIRST_NAME      end) AS "First author first name",
    min (case LIST_INDEX when 0 then NAME_LAST_NAME end) AS     "First author last name",
    min (case LIST_INDEX when 1 then NAME_FIRST_NAME end) AS "Second author first name",
    min (case LIST_INDEX when 1 then NAME_LAST_NAME end) AS "Second author last name"´, etc.

Not ideal, as I have to hardcode 60 lines to accommodate for 30 possible authors, in which case most columns will be 'null'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the XMLELEMENT, XMLAGG and XMLATTRIBUTE functions in SQL to generate the XML, XMLAGG will aggregate/roll-up repeating rows, so it will represent parent-child as element/sub-element.

You can write functions that return XMLTYPE, and then reference these in the queries to make you code easier to understand.

Something like:

```
select  XMLELEMENT( "List", 
           XMLAGG ( XMLELEMENT ( "Book",
              XMLATTRIBUTES (NAME_FIRST_NAME,
        NAME_LAST_NAME,
        LIST_INDEX,
        PUBLICATION_ID ) ) ) )

from CLASSIFIED_AUTHOR_ASSOC CAA
join PUBLICATION        PUB
on CAA.PUBLICATION_ID = PUB.ID

where CAA.PUBLICATION_ID IN 
    (select PUBLICATION_ID 
    from CLASSIFIED_AUTHOR_ASSOC 
    where PERSON_ID = '127746')

order by CAA.PUBLICATION_ID, CAA.LIST_INDEX ASC
```

Experiment with this to get an idea of how it works and how to get it to do what you want.

If you want to translate the LIST_INDEX to something like "Author One", "Author Two" etc consider using "TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (LIST_INDEX, 'j'), 'jsp')" to convert the number LIST_INDEX to a text string .

Soory for not creating a more concrete example ... I haven't got access to my database to test, but I hope teh above gives you some helpful hints.

Comment: Thanks! I had been looking into Oracle's XML functions, but was a little intimidated (since I have to do quite a lot of conditional stuff) and was hoping to do the conversion in Python. Maybe I should use this opportunity to get familiar with the built-in XML functions.